# Another app / layout in jhipster generated angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster, angular-router

In the standard Angular application that is generated by jhipster, there is one application which has a navbar with many routerlinks, which are used to navigate to entities CRUD, or administration menus.

I am looking for a way that, while preserving most part of jhipster generated code, can give me the possibility to build a secondary application (e.g. "#/app") that has a different navbar (with no admin links) and different pages, which use case is to give a rich layout to the customer while using most of the generated angular code related to entities and services. /app should be a hierarchy of components, while the current jhipster is moved into a similar hierarchy, "admin".

I've tried this approach:

`app.route.ts`

```
export const navbarRoute: Route = {
    path: '',
    component: NavbarComponent,
    outlet: 'navbar'
};

export const playRoute: Route = {
   path: '',
   component: AppbarComponent,
   outlet: 'navbar'
};
```

then in `layout-routing.module.ts`

```
const LAYOUT_ROUTES = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'app', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'admin', children: [
        navbarRoute,
        ...errorRoute]
    },
    {
        path: 'app', children: [
        playRoute,
        ...errorRoute]
    }
];
```

This way I have two different navbars, and while it seems to be fine, I have to change every url for every other router link, for example if I have an entity book, I will have to go to change in book.route.ts path to admin/book, and so on. It just doesn't seems right, but maybe it could be a step in the right direction, isn't it?

Comment: Hi @suprandr, how did you end up structuring your app? I am facing the same issue and looking for a clean implementation

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I don't recall the setup I did.